# Mobile Safari 5.0 sending me to about:blank on login/logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile, safari

When I log in, log out, or do a post I am getting a "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request on a dirt old iPad with mobile safari 5.0. This error is followed by an error from jQuery, "Result of expression 'a' [undefined] is not an object." Upon returning to the original url the page loads as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here >> http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13546

Looks like it is throwing a xss error incorrectly.